# RESTAR TIEMPO Y MOSTRAR TOTAL - MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo la siguiente duda y no se puedan ayudarme.

Tengo esta tabla en la BD, es un registro de asistencias que guarda la hora de ingreso a laborar, hora de ingreso a almuerzo, salida de almuerzo, salida de laborar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla hay datos almacenados de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo realizar es lo siguiente:

Restar las siguientes columnas:

hora_s_labor - hora_i_labor = DATO1 (resultado de horas de labor) 
hora_s_alm - hora_i_alm = DATO2 (resultado de horas de almuerzo)

DATO1 - DATO2 = Horas trabajadas diariamente

Al final de las operaciones quiero imprimir la suma total de las horas trabajadas diariamente.

ESTE ES MI CÓDIGO QUE MUESTRA SOLO LOS DATOS DE LA BD:

```
<?php $querybase = "SELECT * FROM asistencias WHERE user_dni = '$f_user' AND MONTH(fecha) = '$f_mes' AND YEAR(fecha) = '$f_anio' ORDER BY fecha";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$querybase); ?>

<table id="data-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>DNI</th>
                            <th>FECHA</th>
                            <th>Hora Inicio A</th>
                            <th>Hora Salida A</th>
                            <th>Hora Inicio R</th>
                            <th>Hora Salida R</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if ($result1) {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_user_dni']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_fecha']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_hora_i_labor']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_hora_i_alm']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_hora_s_alm']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['asis_hora_s_labor']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa `TIMEDIFF` para restar y sumar desde MySQL así:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("13:10:11", "13:10:10");
```

Más información en la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) o en este [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timediff/).